# How to map <C-/> to toggle comments in vim?

Tags: vim

I use vim under iterm2. I'm using the NERDCommenter plugin, and I'd like to use Ctrl+/ to toggle comments (Trying to switch from Idea/Eclipse to vim). This is my mapping in the .vimrc :

```
 nmap <C-/> <leader>c<Space>
 vmap <C-/> <leader>c<Space>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

For some reason, vim registers `<C-/>` as `<C-_>` (you can see it in insert mode using `<C-v><C-/>`). It can be the terminal or a historical design thing that terminal apps have to suffer.

And Gvim doesn't even try to recognize `<C-/>`. Sees it as single `/`.

Comment: Thanks! I just mapped it to <C-_> and it works! Original idea was to map to <D-/> but that doesn't even register in vim, I think...

Comment: Is this only on iterm2? I'm using Terminal.app and just get the bell ding error and nothing happens. However, when I actually press the `_` key in the `<C-_>` binding, it will do the comment toggle. How can I get Terminal.app to use the `<C-/>` binding ?

Comment: Note on the above ^^ `<C-_>` only works on the underscore on numeric keypads (10key), not on the apple compact keyboard. Additionally, `<C-/>` is not a valid keycode (apparently there are limited `CTRL + letters` and `/` is not one of them). Source: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-map-Ctrl-td1192843.html

Comment: `<C-_>` for terminal and iTerm works like a charm, but it doesn't for macvim. Did anyone happen to find a way around it by any chance?

Comment: It's tmux. For whatever reason, <C-/> "[doesn't exist](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/697#issuecomment-268998386)" in tmux. Outside of a tmux session, it seems to work fine in modern terminals.

Answer (score 24):

Here is how you can do it regaining the selection if you are in visual mode:

```
nmap <C-_>   <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
vmap <C-_>   <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle<CR>gv
```

Comment: For me <Bar> made the trick, as I had <CR> already mapped:

`vmap <C-_>   <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle<Bar>gv`

Answer (score 4):

Just to sum up the information from other answers. For me (there might be a difference due to the fact that I'm using [neovim](https://neovim.io/)) `<C-/>` works fine on Windows, but I need to use `<C-_>` on Linux:

```
if has('win32')
  nmap <C-/> <leader>c<Space>
  vmap <C-/> <leader>c<Space>
else
  nmap <C-_> <leader>c<Space>
  vmap <C-_> <leader>c<Space>
endif
```

Comment: I use neovide with `neovide --remote-tcp=localhost:6666`  and running neovim in wsl, can not use  nmap <C-/> <leader>c<Space>

Comment: That is untrue. It might have been the case on old Windows systems but not anymore. At least on Windows 11, using Windows Terminal and neovim, `<c-/>` isn't recognized and `<c-_>` works as on Unix systems.

Comment: Secondly, this is a bad idea to remap another mapping. Always a better idea to go to the source, using the original command `nerdcommenter#Comment(0,"toggle")` (the replacement of the deprecated `NERDCommenterToggle`). This will prevent issues if some parts of the old mapping are remapped to something else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using iTerm2 + vim, maybe the following steps can help you:

1. Add following code to your `.vimrc` file.

   > map ,cc <plug>NERDCommenterToggle

   or if you have defined your <leader> as ,

   > map <leader>cc <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
2. Check if you can use `,cc` to toggle comments in vim
3. Open `iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Keys`, click the `+` button
4. Select `Send Text with "vim" Special Chars`, enter `,cc`, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJLW3.jpg).
5. Now you can use `C-/` to toggle comments in vim.