# How to map <C-/> in Mac Terminal in Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to map Ctrl+/ to use NerdCommenter. It works perfect in Linux terminal, but not works in Mac default terminal. How can I fix it?

```
noremap <C-_> :call NERDComment(0, "Toggle")<cr>
```

I read this thread, but didn't find a solution: [How to map <C-/> to toggle comments in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051837/how-to-map-c-to-toggle-comments-in-vim)

Comment: Try `<C-v><C-/>` in insert mode; compare it with `<C-v><C-_>` (`[Control]+[Shift]+[-]`) — are the results the same?

Comment: @phd `noremap <C-v><C-_> :call NERDComment(0, "Toggle")<cr>`? No, not works :(