# How do I use ctrl + / as a shortcut in vim using map? (<C-_> doesn't work)

Tags: vim, nerdcommenter

I'm using a plugin for vim called NERDCommenter which allows me to toggle line of code's commented state. The thing is I want to change the shortcut to ctrl + / or command + /. Online (from other posts I read) it says to not use `<C-/>`, but to instead use `<C-_>`. This does not work and only maps the toggle comment command to ctrl underscore.

Here is the code I'm using to do this:

```
nnoremap <C-_> :call NERDComment(0, "toggle")<CR>
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using gvim by any chance? In console vim and nvim-qt, control-/ is recognized as <C-_>,  but gvim seems to not know what to do, and just registers it as a slash with no modifier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map <C-/> to toggle comments in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051837/how-to-map-c-to-toggle-comments-in-vim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of writing this, in `MacOS` using the current/built-in `Terminal` app (without the use of other software), unfortunately it is ***not possible*** to map a `Vim` shortcut using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

This is because neither of these key sequences have control code encodings (more on that [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24261/how-do-i-send-c-that-is-control-slash-to-the-terminal) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/430308/precedent-for-terminal-key-bindings-for-windows-or-mac-cmd-key)).

---

### Option #1 (recommended)

Map <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to toggle NERDCommenter → mac users must use the real character (÷) generated by Option/Alt sequence to do this:

```
nmap ÷ <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
vmap ÷ <plug>NERDCommenterToggle<CR>gv
```

Only works if *Terminal > Preferences > Profiles [settings] > Keyboard > 'Use Option as Meta Key'* is toggled ***OFF***. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501092/can-i-map-alt-key-in-vim).

### Option #2 - MacVim

You can use [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim) which allows you to map the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key with `<D->`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990454/how-to-map-mac-command-key-in-vim).

### Option #3 - iTerm2

Use `iTerm2` for your terminal app. This way you can map <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to `<C-_>` and it will work. For <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to work, you'll have to create a new keyboard shortcut to send as an escape sequence to `Vim`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060569/mapping-command-s-to-w-in-vim) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051837/how-to-map-c-to-toggle-comments-in-vim).

---

I wouldn't advise this, but you could also use a program to remap your <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> modifier keys every time you open a specific app like `Terminal`. `iTerm2` works for this task too, as well as programs like [Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner) -- for older versions of `MacOS`. According to [this post](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/808), the newer [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) requires some tweaking for app-specific remapping.

**More Resources**: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/387897/can-i-use-the-cmd-key-in-terminal-vim-at-all), [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236119/how-do-i-swap-ctrl-and-alt-in-just-the-terminal), and [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6191).

Comment: I've already seen that post and tried that. As I've already said, I tried to use <C-_> but it maps to ctrl underscore instead of ctrl slash.

Comment: @yona The correct way to say "your question has already been answered here" is to [flag it as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/20/linking-duplicate-questions/).

Comment: @Zemelware just to be clear, you've added `nmap <C-_>   <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle` to your `.vimrc` and when you try `Ctrl+/` in Normal mode, nothing happens?

Comment: @yona, yes I've typed exactly that in my `.vimrc` and tried the shortcut in Normal mode, but `ctrl+/` doesn't comment/uncomment lines, only `ctrl+_` does (and wouldn't that make sense anyway because then how would you map ctrl + underscore to a command?). Also, I'm on macOS but I don't know if that matters.

Comment: @JakeGrossman this is not a duplicate. I explicitly stated in the title that `<C-_>` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Zemelware I didn’t mean to imply that it was. “Was your question answered here” is not a good answer, was my point.

Comment: @Zemelware it very much _does matter_ that you're using MacOS -> see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24261/how-do-i-send-c-that-is-control-slash-to-the-terminal. Are you using the builtin Terminal app?

Comment: @yona yes I am using the built-in terminal app. That seems to be the issue as I tried it with iTerm2 and it worked. Is there any possible way to do this with the built-in terminal app?

Comment: @Zemelware I have just updated my answer--was this what you were hoping for?

Comment: @yona thank you. It sucks that I can't do this with the default terminal app, but I think I'm going to switch to iTerm2. Thanks for your help!